# Sendmail on hpux: error dsn 5.0.0

Tags: permissions, sendmail

I am running `sendmail` as user `smmsp`.
I have create `user,group` with same name. `sendmail` starts ok, but when I try to send email
outside of localhost give me this error:

```
Jan  3 20:46:59 hpux2 sm-mta[20893]: t03JkwJb020892: t03JkxJb020893: DSN: Insufficient permission
```

I gave these permissions:

```
chmod 2755  /usr/sbin/sendmail
chown root:smmsp /usr/sbin/sendmail
chmod 700   /var/spool/mail
chown smmsp:smmsp /var/spool/mail /var/spool/clientmqueue/
chmod 700 /var/spool/mail
chmod 770 /var/spool/clientmqueue/
chmod 755 /etc/mail
```

Of course I have restarted the daemon.
What did I miss?

Comment: Is `smmsp`the group of `/usr/sbin/sendmail`? Try to relax the permissions on the directories until this works gradually, then you probably get a better indication of what is the exact problem.

Comment: Yes it is,I have forgot to add in question

Comment: I am not sure if having `700` on `/var/spool/mail` and `2755` on `sendmail` is enough, maybe you need `770`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: was not a problem of permission,but a problem of mailx.
On hpux is totally different mailx,and not allow "starttls" wich is 
required by my mail server.
I have to use an external mailx or try to put starttls on sendmail if possible
anyway thanks to all for help